# sed - remove specific subscript from string

Tags: sed, shell

please provide me a sed oneliner which provides this output:
sdc3 sdc2 
for Input :
sdc3[1] sdc2[0]

I mean remove all subscript value from the string ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed 's/\[[^]]*\]//g'
```

reads: substitute any string with literal "[" followed by zero or more characters that aren't a "]", and then the closing "]", with an empty string.

You need the `[^]]` bit to prevent greedy matching treating "[1] sdc2[0]" as a single match in your sample string.

---

As for your comment:

```
sed 's#\([^[ ]*\)\[[^]]*\]#/dev/\1#g'
```

- I switch the seperator from the usual '/' to '#', just to avoid escaping the `/dev/` bit you asked for (I won't say "for clarity")
- the `\(...\)` bit matches a subgroup, here sdc2 or whatever, so we can refer to it in the replacement
- the subgroup uses a similar character class to the one we used discarding the index: `[^[ ]` means any character except an "[" (again, to avoid greedily matching the index) or a space (assuming your values are space-delimited as per your post)
- the replacement is now the literal "/dev/" followed by the first (and only) subgroup match
- the `g` flag at the end tells it to perform multiple matches per line, instead of stopping at the first one

Comment: Thanks! help..can u add /dev before the string : something like /dev/sdc3 /dev/sdc2

Comment: <<As for your comment: Thanks Again!